# Include post_date in search

Tags: plugins, posts, search, date, date-time

I'd like to search posts by year. For example, I could type in "June 2015" and all posts from that time appear. Or, I could type "2015" and all posts from the year appear.

Currently, I have Relevanssi set to index all public posts and attachments, including all categories and tags. Yet, posts from a searched time (ex, "2015") are not populating, unless the term is in the title or post content.

I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. Hoping for some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to receive the solution from the developer. Add the below code into functions.php and then rebuild the Relvanssi index. This worked for me.

```
function rlv_index_post_date( $content, $post ) {
    $date = get_the_time( "F Y", $post->ID );
    $content .= " $date";
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'relevanssi_content_to_index', 'rlv_index_post_date', 10, 2 );
```